# react-native run-ios is not working

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, npm-install

I have a react native ios and it was working fine, suddnly it's working only in Xcode but not in terminal using this command:

```
react-native run-ios
react-native run-ios --device
```

Both of command are not working in the root directory, I tried to delete node_modules folder then run:

```
npm install; react-native link;
```

Unfortunatly it's not working, here are my logs:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any Help!

Comment: In which folder are you ?

Comment: Can you show me an ls and pwd please ?

Comment: @JulienKode I'm in the root folder, I updated the question by ls command

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seems that you have a lot of missing libraries which are not downloaded for some reason, I recommend that you should delete all downloadable libs then start over again:

- delete **node_modules/** folder

  - delete **ios/Pods** folder
  - delete **ios/build** folder
  - run: `npm install`
- run: `cd ios; pod install; cd../`
- run: `react-native link`

That's it

Comment: [!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory. I am getting this when I run "pod install"

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve it by upgrading node.

```
brew upgrade node
```

type this in terminal.

Comment: its $brew upgrade node

Comment: It is `brew upgrade node`. `brew update` does not take a package name and is intended to update brew itself only.

Comment: In my case, I had to downgrade node to version 8 to work on some legacy Angular application. I used nvm to upgrade back to a recent version of node.

Answer (score 1):

There could be various reasons, in my case it was due to some of the libraries being used and I was able to figure out the solution by changing the Build Active Architecture Option.

Setting the target->Build Settings->Build Active Architecture Only option for both the app and Pods target (for both debug and Release) to Yes made it work with react native in command line while setting the above options to No made them work with Xcode.

Comment: The answer should be a commentary. It does not provide an actual solution, but only points out possible causes to the problem presented in the question.

Comment: Actually this presents the possible problem plus the solution for my case, which none of the above answers list. I have edited the answer in case that was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working using the instructions here facebook/watchman#376 :

```
sudo launchctl unload -F ~root/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist
```

Don't know enough about watchman to understand why it was running as a service. But it worked anyway.

or

Uninstalling and reinstalling Watchman fixed this issue for me.